# No symbols loaded error after installing Update 3 for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

After updating to VS 2013 Update 3 my web service now breaks every time I run it in debug mode.

I get this error each time because it VS is attempting to load the System.Web.pdb file and cannot find it or load it:

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll
```

Symbol load information:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\System.Web.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\System.Web.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\symbols\dll\System.Web.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
C:\Windows\dll\System.Web.pdb: Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

Sometime it is a different .pdb file but it is always a .pdb file that is failing to load.  Why is it even attempting to load these symbols and how do I get it to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the similar problem when I moved to Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. Try to disable Visual Studio Browser Linkage by adding this to your web config, I hope it works for you too:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was really struggling to find an answer on this.  That worked perfectly.